# return data from method (JSON Array)

Tags: java, android, json

I have one method with this url:
String url = "http://brunos.000webhostapp.com/teste/obter_id.php?descricao=" + value;

And i want to return the result of this method.

i have tried the VolleyCallback callback but i cant send the value to the method

```
package com.example.fabio.domoticaa;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class Divi_Dispo extends AppCompatActivity {
    String x;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_divi__dispo);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        final String[] count = new String[1];
        final String[] id = new String[1];
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String value = intent.getStringExtra("divisao");
        final EditText nomediv = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
        Count(value);
        nomediv.setText(x);//want set th result of Count(value)
    }
    public void Count(String value) {
        final String[] count = new String[1];
        // Send data
        try {
            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(Divi_Dispo.this);
            String url = "http://brunos.000webhostapp.com/teste/obter_id.php?descricao=" + value ;
            JsonArrayRequest jsonRequest = new JsonArrayRequest
                    (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(response.get(0)));
                                count[0] = jObj.getString("COUNT(id)");//want return this valor
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            error.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    });
            queue.add(jsonRequest);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        } finally {
        }
    }
    public interface VolleyCallback {
        void onSuccess(String result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you are asking for homework help.  While we have no issues with that per se, please observe these [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845), and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: is now a good question?

Comment: Not really.  You need to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem.